# Help me optimize this scrollTo

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm no pro in JavaScript. Please help me review this code. I would appreciate any suggestions!

**JavaScript:**

```
var y_offset, /*current position of window*/
    distance_from_current_position, /*different between current position and target*/
    body_height, /*hight of body*/
    window_height, /*height of window*/
    position_of_target, /*target position*/
    max_scroll, /*max position to scroll to*/
    up_or_down, /*scroll up or down*/
    my_classes = document.querySelectorAll('.y');

function scroll_function(target) {

    y_offset = window.pageYOffset;

    distance_from_current_position = target - window.pageYOffset;

    setTimeout(function () {

        if (distance_from_current_position !== 0) {
            if (up_or_down) {
                if (y_offset < target - 5) {
                    window.scroll(0, y_offset + (distance_from_current_position / 3))
                } else {
                    window.scroll(0, y_offset + 1)
                }
                if (y_offset < position_of_target - 1) {
                    scroll_function(target);
                }
            } else {
                if (y_offset > target + 5) {
                    window.scroll(0, y_offset + (distance_from_current_position / 3))
                } else {
                    window.scroll(0, y_offset - 1)
                }
                if (y_offset > position_of_target + 1) {
                    scroll_function(target);
                }
            }
        }

    }, 50)
}

function click_function(i) {
    my_classes[i].onclick = function () {
        body_height = document.body.clientHeight;

        position_of_target = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-y')).offsetTop;

        window_height = window.innerHeight;

        max_scroll = body_height - window_height;

        if (window.pageYOffset < position_of_target) {
            up_or_down = 1
        } else {
            up_or_down = 0
        }

        if (position_of_target > max_scroll) {
            position_of_target = max_scroll;
        }
        $y_1(position_of_target);

    };

}

for (var i = 0; i < my_classes.length; i++) {
    click_function(i);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title></title>
<ul class=ul>
<li><a class=y data-y=id1>Scroll to id1</a>
<li><a class=y data-y=id2>Scroll to id2</a>
<li><a class=y data-y=id3>Scroll to id´3</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve exactly? It seems cleaner to use built in [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo) or even using `<a href="#elementid">`. Sometimes there is a good reason not to use a built in method but sometimes not.

Comment: Thanks James, I will add your changes. One thing would like is a smoother easeing effect than (distance_from_current_position / 3). Any idea on how to fixa that?

Comment: Again what are you trying to solve exactly? I'd love to post an answer but I can't see any reason for the code. A code-less solution would be much better in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

From a once over:

- This code does not work, you did not provide `$y_1`, I am assuming you meant `scroll_function`
- I built a JsBin for this : http://jsbin.com/sihoj/1/edit, because you keep calling `scroll_function`, you can actually prevent the user from reaching the navigation links again, that's not a good approach
- As James Khoury mentioned, why not use `<a href="#elementid">` or `scrollTo` ?
- You should use lowerCamelCase
- This :

  ```
  if (position_of_target > max_scroll) {
      position_of_target = max_scroll;
  }
  ```

  could be

  ```
  position_of_target = Math.min( position_of_target , max_scroll );
  ```

  I feel this reflects better what you are trying to accomplish

**Naming**

I would much rather see

```
//Distance from currrent position
distance = target - window.pageYOffset;
```

than

```
distance_from_current_position = target - window.pageYOffset;
```

your code becomes a bit unwieldy when you have too many long variable names

If you have `target` and would have `distance` , then I would also go for `offset`, `y_offset` looks ugly.

Also here

```
position_of_target = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-y')).offsetTop;
```

you should have some deep thoughts about the variable name, position implies usually an x/y coordinate, but you are really dealing here with an offset from the top.

Finally : `up_or_down` is a terrible name, there is no logical connection for 1 being up, and 0 being down. At the very least you should consider 
`var UP = true, DOWN = false` or `var UP = 1, DOWN = 0` if you don't want to use booleans.

**Magic Constants**

`/ 3` <- That `3` should be a well named constant
`target - 5` <- That `5` should be a well named constant

**Fake Booleans**

This:

```
    if (window.pageYOffset < position_of_target) {
        up_or_down = 1
    } else {
        up_or_down = 0
    }
```

is letting `up_or_down` be a fake boolean, you should go for

```
    up_or_down = (window.pageYOffset < position_of_target)
```

especially since you are doing falsey comparisons to `up_or_down` any way.

**DRY**

This:

```
        if (up_or_down) {
            if (y_offset < target - 5) {
                window.scroll(0, y_offset + (distance_from_current_position / 3))
            } else {
                window.scroll(0, y_offset + 1)
            }
            if (y_offset < position_of_target - 1) {
                scroll_function(target);
            }
        } else {
            if (y_offset > target + 5) {
                window.scroll(0, y_offset + (distance_from_current_position / 3))
            } else {
                window.scroll(0, y_offset - 1)
            }
            if (y_offset > position_of_target + 1) {
                scroll_function(target);
            }
        }
```

could be

```
    var vector = up_or_down ? -1 : +1; 

    if (y_offset < target + 5 * vector ) {
        window.scroll(0, y_offset + (distance_from_current_position / 3))
    } else {
        window.scroll(0, y_offset - vector)
    }
    if (y_offset < position_of_target + vector) {
        scroll_function(target);
    }
```